# Streaming the recorded screen to another phone via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, stream, screen, record

I'm into a research project recently where I need to record a GLSurfaceView and stream it via Bluetooth to another phone (device B). The Other phone should display it.

My objectives are the following:

1. List item
2. Determine if it is possible
3. Determine if we can get enough frame rates in order to be enjoyable for the client.
4. To determine how this impacts the battery life time.

I started with a simplified example where:
 - in the Renderer object I took a screenshot in every frame
 - serialized it as a byte array
 - set it to the other device
 - build a bitmap out of it
 - display it

With this I could achieve a ~10 frame per second rate, which is a bit better then expected (800x600 resolution)

**Question:**
Now I would like to make a video stream and sent it to the device B. Decode it and display it.
I've got lots of similar examples on the http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/ maintained by fadden

Before I dig in myself I wanted to ask somebody's opinion about it.
1. Are there any already made examples?
2. Which is the adviced direction to start
3. Is it even possible?
4. What performance can be expected?

Thank you